# docker containers are not communicating internally with prometheus

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to monitor a webserver frontend page using prometheus and docker.
In the Prometheus I'm getting error as connection refused.

Running the two containers using below command.

```
docker-compose up
```

files :
docker-compose.yaml

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the goal is to connect from the 'prometheus' to the 'server' container, this line in the prometheus config:

```
- targets: ['localhost:9393']
```

should become this

```
- targets: ['server:9300']
```

Comment: if you still receive an error, please do show

Comment: See how it says 127.0.0.1? it should say 'server' instead, that container is a different ip address.

Comment: that's why I put it in my answer :)